# Mapping eigen matrix into c++ vector

Tags: c++, memory, vector, eigen

I want to write an Eigen dense matrix into a c++ vector.
I can preallocate a c++ vector, but it seems I cannot do that on a eigen matrix.
I need preallocation, cause i have my reasons. So i want to map the rowmajor ordered matrix into a vector.

I have the address of the matrix written as vector with matrixXd.data()

It prints me an address.

How can i access to its elements? For example I want to store them in another c++ vector

I tried with:

```
vector<double> array;
for (int i=0; i<6; i++){
    array[i] = *mat.data() + i*sizeof(double);
}
```

But it gives me segmentation fault.

Comment: Declare your array as `vector<double> array(6);` to make a 6-element vector. The segmentation fault comes from the `array[i]` expression where you access memory that does not belong to the vector. Regarding accessing the Eigen matrix check the docs , there's much better ways than `.data() + ..` to it.  Assuming a 2d matrix you should be able to do `vector<double> array(mat.reshape().begin(), mat.reshape().end());` but verify yourself

Comment: It does belong to the vector. pushback() and emplaceback() are just the ugly brothers of that operation. Check the time benchamrk yourself. It's called assignement, and it's the basic operation a vector does.

Comment: I should add that ths is my matrix: Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor> Eigenvectors(row_size, 2); and it doesn't even have the reshape functionality

Comment: No, Nikos is right. You fail to allocate memory for the vector since you don't pass an initial size to the vector constructor. Therefore you just dereference a null pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bugs in your code and discussions on the proper use of `std::vector` aside, this should do what you want in an efficient manner.

```cpp
using RowMajorMatrixXd = Eigen::Matrix<
      double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>;
// could be any Eigen expression
RowMajorMatrixXd x = RowMajorMatrixXd::Random(4, 6);
// allocate vector with size x.rows() * x.cols()
std::vector<double> array(x.size());
// map vector as an Eigen matrix with the appropriate shape
// then assign the content of x
RowMajorMatrixXd::Map(array.data(), x.rows(), x.cols()) = x;
```

In comments, the use of [`reshaped`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReshape.html) was suggested. I recommend avoiding that since it often produces very inefficient code since mapping indices can be relatively expensive, especially when not known at compile time, and it also disables Eigen's explicit vectorization, though the compiler may still try to do it.